# Show comments on the category page in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to show inline comments after each post on my category page using comments_template() tag.

However, the comments or comment form are not showing up for some reason. The same tag works fine on the content-single page.

By the way I am using WP 3.2.1 along with the twentyeleven theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to do so by forcing the loading of comments. You can force loading of comment by setting the global variable '$withcomments'

For example, you can put this code in your functions.php

```
add_filter('wp_head','sb_force_comment');
function sb_force_comment( ) {
global $withcomments;
    if(is_category())
        $withcomments = true; //force to show the comment on category page
  }
```

It will show the comments as well as the form too on the category page if you are using comments_template()  on your category page.

In case you don't want to show the comment form on the category page, you can do it by putting the following code in your functions.php

```
add_filter('comments_open','sb_fake_comments_closed_on_category',20,2);

function sb_fake_comments_closed_on_category ($is_open,$post_id){
  if(is_category())
    return false;
  return $is_open;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

comments_template starts with the code:

```
if ( !(is_single() || is_page() || $withcomments) || empty($post) )
   return;
```

So that only works for posts and single pages.

You can either create a page that lists your categories and also uses comments_template.
Or use [get_comments](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments) to get all comments for a post and then manually loop through them and generate the output. You can also set the global variable $withcomments, see answer from sbrajesh.